# Tools to convert code in PHP to ASP.NET

Tags: php, asp.net

I am working on a self project, where I am trying to convert a website written in php to ASP.NET(C#). I came across a php to ASP.net migration assistant, but this comes as an addon for VS 2003.

- Is there a migration assistant add in for VS 2008.
- Tips/tricks for going through the migration.
- Are their any other open source/Commercial tools to accomplish the above.

I understand that there cannot be a fool proof tool. What I am looking for is a tool which does the basic job of conversion, and I can take it up from their to resolve the differences/ parts which could not be converted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the best conversiontool is your two hands + you brain.

But that takes a lot of time ofcourse...

Comment: That would give an opportunity to check everything works properly as well... and you can get rid of any nasty bits that have been on the to do list for too long!

Comment: I agree that is the best way. But with a large code base and single hand at work, I was looking for a tool which can reduce my task.